# jquery ajax post redirect issue

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

The div containing the form, which is included in a post div

```
<div class="add-comment">
    <form action="post.php?post=<?php echo $post->id; ?>" class="commentform" method="post">
        <textarea name="content" class="comment_content"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit_comment" value="Add Comment" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the code to handle the post

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_comment'])){
    if(isset($_GET['post'])){
        $content = strip_tags(trim($_POST['content']));
        $comment = Comment::make($_GET['post'],$content,$_SESSION['user_id'],1);
        if($comment && $comment->save()){
            echo "Post submitted succesfully.";         
        }else{
            $message = Comment::$comment_message;
        }       
    }
}
```

The code without the JS is working as expected.
What I'm trying to do is submit the comment without the page refreshing.
Here is the JS code I tried but as it seems failed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.commentform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var form = $(this);
        var posturl = form.attr('action');
        var comment = form.find('textarea[name="content"]').val();
        //var comment = $(this).closest($('.comment_content'));
        $.post(posturl, comment, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

What is going wrong? After pressing the submit button the page remains but the comment doesn't get submitted. (i can tell that by reloading the page)

Comment: How are you saving the comment? Can you describe HOW it's failing? Do you have Firebug or any other web developer tool that can show you potential JS errors?

Comment: firebug doesn't show any errors at all.
im saving by querying the database with "INSERT..", but i guess there isn't any problem with the php since the code without the js runs perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not posting a key - value pair but just the value:

```
var comment = form.find('textarea[name="content"]').val();
```

should be something like:

```
var comment = {'content': form.find('textarea[name="content"]').val()};
```

Apart from that you need to post all values as your php will fail if you don't so you are better of using something like:

```
var comment = form.serialize();
```

**Edit:** As you still have a problem, You need to `console.log` all your javascript variables before you post; if the js is in another folder, the action / url is probably wrong.

Comment: i've tried .serialize(); and the other way but still nothing happens, the page stays as it is and the comment doesn't get submitted..

Comment: @jeroen, The Data variable, comment, was a good catch. Make sure you're incorporating that line.

Comment: using var comment = {'content': form.find('textarea[name="content"]').val()};
i did console.log(posturl) which gives the url as it is in the action attribute of <form> (which is expected) and with the console.log(comment['content']) i get the content from the textarea which is also expected..

Comment: @Systemfreak Yes, but you are only sending the variable `content` and in your php script you are using `if(isset($_POST['submit_comment'])){
` and you are not posting that variable.

Comment: oh god i feel so blind-stupid, i didn't even notice that.
thanks a lot, that was my problem!